# How do I change the visibility of my Steam screenshots in batch?

Tags: steam

The screenshot manager in Steam allows you to change the visibility of your Steam screenshots, but is there a way to select them all without having to select each of them individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First go to your screenshot page by clicking on your username and then content.

Select Screenshots.

[image]

Click on Image wall.

[image]

Select Grid.

[image]

Click Select All and then Make Private.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering why the option to select all screenshots is missing from Image wall view...

Comment: No problem. I'm guessing that functionality is missing in image wall because the screenshots' display states vary in size and location.